# How can I fix this invalid error on google spreadsheet about the data validation

Tags: google-sheets

> Invalid: Input must fall within specified range

[image: Invalid: Input must fall within specified range]

on A1 I'm using the `=Now()`

on A4 I'm using the Data Validation

I need the dropdown list cell so I can specify what time I did something.

can someone help me with this please, been trying to fix this for hours now, can't seem to find it on google too. would be a big help, helping me with this one.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve with that dropdown?

Comment: As @player0 has already asked, you should try to explain what is your final objective, and the reasoning behind the data validation in A4. What does your dropdown contains?